# How to get info for multiple job IDs from Oozie through Knox?

Tags: rest, hadoop, oozie, knox-gateway, bigdata

The URL to get info for one job from Oozie through Knox is
/v1/job/{oozie-id}?show=info

Is there any URL to do this as a batch, for several IDs at once?

Comment: Knox is just a proxy, it's the Oozie API syntax that matters. So RTFM: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WebServicesAPI.html#Job_Information

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. My question was: I have 10 IDs (workflows, coordinators, whatever, does Oozie support a URL to which I can send all 10 at once and get a JSON Array of responses? I'm calling the URL mentioned in the question for each ID now. I mentioned through KNOX just to give more info about the situation, the URL is for the Oozie API, from the manual.